# Get Android Dependencies to an Empty Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have cloned a github repo. (Which only has a README)

I want to get android dependencies into that repository. (The whole android files and structures that comes with creating a new project from the Android Studio Wizard).

Is this possible.?

I need to build an app from that repo (make commits and push to the repo)

I have tried to create a new seperate project from Android Studio Wizard and copy the files into the cloned repo directory, but it didn't work like I wanted.

Is there an option to maybe 'Create an Android Project inside a project" :)

Answer (score 0):

"it didn't work like I wanted" is not a valid error description, but a mere complaint.
Just move the `.git` directory into your Android project, then pull, commit and push.
However, creating a new Android project in the repo directory should be the same.